# Is it possible to view Ruby on Rails source code in Chrome's Developer Tools?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome

I know I can view the sourcecode for a website by clicking on "View Source" or "Developer Tools". I was interested in learning more, so I looked for some Chrome Extensions.

I downloaded "RailsPanels", but it seems like I can only use that by including a gem in my gemfile. This also doesn't show the Ruby on Rails sourcecode, only the standard HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

I'm interested in viewing the actual Ruby on Rails code of a website. I would like to know if there are any ways I can do this, or any extensions?

I have researched Developer Tools extensively and searched for this on Google. Unfortunately, I could not find what I was looking for.

Comment: It depends on how that site is set up. You *shouldn't* be able to, and by default you can't, but it's possible for the administrator/webmaster to configure/program a site to allow it.

Comment: It would be quite a security risk if you could access a website / web app's source code like that.

Comment: @PaulRichter the open source community would heavily disagree with that statement

Comment: @ascar How do you mean?

Comment: @PaulRichter open source community advances the view that making your code publicly available (open source) is not a security risk. Some even say it rather improves security by letting a community find risks and bugs. In general a software is not more secure just because "bad guys" can't look at the source. Most of the attacks do not profit of looking at the source code anyway.

Comment: @ascar Ah ok. Yes, those are good points in regards to the open source community. But I believe we're talking about two different things; you're talking about open source libraries, I (and the OP) are talking about the actual implementation details of a system, which wouldn't necessarily have the benefit of open source scrutiny. Information regarding database details, sql queries, input sanitization (which hopefully is already done securely), or who knows what else could be potentially damaging, either to the system (from a security standpoint) or the company /owner itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible because the Ruby code of the web site is never sent as part of the request made by the browser.

If you want the source code of a Rails application, it would be better to contact the owner directly.